Cannot use git button in Rstudio after adding SSH key

I can use git terminal to pull and push to github remote repository, and need password every time.
I want to know how to use those bottons and not to input password every time.
thank you.

https://forum.posit.co/t/push-and-pull-buttons-for-git-are-not-enabled-in-rstudio/19842 solved my question that pull and push buttons are not enabled. But I still need password.

Create a personal access token in Github and pass it instead of the account password.
to create personal access token go to Settings --> Developer Settings --> Personal access tokens.  documentation.
using git with RStudio
